# Basic regarding W3wP.exe - IIS 8

Tags: windows, iis

Sorry if it looks so simple.

Am trying to find when `W3wp.exe` will show up in the process list. Am using Windows 2012 beta with IIS 8. I have web and wcf applications deployed in it. And i tried to browse the pages locally. But am not seeing process.

Please let me know if am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked. But i dono the exact root cause earlier

1. restarted the machine
2. Opened VS With Admin Previlages
3. i was able to see the process listed

Adding up -- For W3wp.exe to appear in the process list instance shuold be running already !

Answer (score 1):

make sure to check

Show all processes in all sessions[image]